# forcing cmake to use specific boost folder

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I try to compile my project while specifying the boost version to be used.

The cmake file has the following

```
  message("before boost include_dir "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
  message("before boost boost_root "${BOOST_ROOT})
  message("before boost boostroot "${BOOSTROOT})
  message("before boost includedir "${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
  message("before boost librarydir "${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})

  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options regex REQUIRED)

  message("after boost include_dir "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
  message("after boost boost_root "${BOOST_ROOT})
  message("after boost boostroot "${BOOSTROOT})
  message("after boost includedir "${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
  message("after boost librarydir "${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
```

when I run cmake

```
build> cmake  -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE -DBOOST_ROOT=/opt/cluster/v1/c++_lib/boost_gcc4.8/1.52.0 -DBoost_DEBUG=ON ..
```

I get in the output

```
before boost include_dir 
before boost boost_root /opt/cluster/v1/c++_lib/boost_gcc4.8/1.52.0
before boost boostroot 
before boost includedir 
before boost librarydir 
Boost  found.
Found Boost components:
   program_options;regex
after boost include_dir /usr/include
after boost boost_root /opt/cluster/v1/c++_lib/boost_gcc4.8/1.52.0
after boost boostroot 
after boost includedir 
after boost librarydir
```

As you can see boost include dir that was found is not mine:

```
after boost include_dir /usr/include
```

And I can't debug because my variable gets ignored since at the end of the output I have this:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    Boost_DEBUG
```

Here is my cmake version

```
build> cmake --version
cmake version 3.0.0
```

1) How can I force cmake to use my boost?

2) Why -DBoost_DEBUG=ON gets ignored?

Comment: can you post your `CMakeLists.txt` file ? It's better for understanding what's going on ?

Comment: Yes, please provide a [mcve]. I tested on my system with CMake versions 2.8.2, 2.8.12.2 and 3.0.2, and got the correct result in all of them.